# Python script for extracting most common words from urls

Tags: python, web-scraping

This Python script extracting most common words from the text file. 
I want to rewrite this code to do the same but from this blog - http://teonite.com/blog/

How can I do this?

The script must go through all 7 pages of the blog, enter each article and get the words and authors names.

```
import collections
import pandas as pd
import inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
# Read input file, note the encoding is specified here
# It may be different in your text file
file = open('PrideandPrejudice.txt', encoding="utf8")


a= file.read()

# Stopwords

stopwords = set(line.strip() for line in open('stopwords.txt'))
stopwords = stopwords.union(set(['mr','mrs','one','two','said']))
# Instantiate a dictionary, and for every word in the file,
# Add to the dictionary if it doesn't exist. If it does, increase 
the count.
wordcount = {}
# To eliminate duplicates, remember to split by punctuation, and use 
case demiliters.
for word in a.lower().split():
    word = word.replace(".","")
    word = word.replace(",","")
    word = word.replace(":","")
    word = word.replace("\"","")
    word = word.replace("!","")
    word = word.replace("â€œ","")
    word = word.replace("â€˜","")
    word = word.replace("*","")
    if word not in stopwords:
        if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[word] += 1
# Print most common word
n_print = int(input("How many most common words to print: 10 "))
print("\nOK. The {} most common words are as 
follows\n".format(n_print))
word_counter = collections.Counter(wordcount)
for word, count in word_counter.most_common(n_print):
    print(word, ": ", count)
# Close the file
file.close()
# Create a data frame of the most common words
# Draw a bar chart
lst = word_counter.most_common(n_print)
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ['Word', 'Count'])
df.plot.bar(x='Word',y='Count')

# Also I need all authors names. This is a loop for
```

Comment: The most straightforward method, though kinda hack-ish is just to save the 7 pages as text documents. You would probably have to use regex to clean out the html elements too, after which, the script that you have should work as-is. Otherwise, you can try the beautifulsoup module as well.

Comment: Which metod do you reccomend ? I would add that the main task is : 1. REST service returning the following statistics in the form of a JSON document 2. 
10 most common words with their number available at the address / stats / 3. 
posts authors with their name available in the address / stats / <author> / available under the address / authors /. 4. data collected in the PostgreSQL database

Comment: It's probably best to separate your concerns. Of the 4 you listed, [1] and [4] can be designed independently of your extraction process, so it's best to think about those separately. So, for [2] and [3], I think a lot depends on whether these are static documents or not. For a one-time extraction, it doesn't really matter which method you use. Manually saving is faster (less development) but I am probably more comfortable with beautifulsoup when it comes to html documents. There's a chance of stripping off valid contents if they're enclosed within a pair of angle brackets

Comment: and two more requirements: [1] for reasons of optimization, the data needed to generate statistics should not be collected with every request sent to / stats / l
ub / stats / <author> /, and preferably asynchronously before the request for any of the services is sent
[2] the maximum service response time is 1 second

Comment: Those sound more like your application design concerns. For the data extraction, if the documents are static, you can always extract, compute statistics and store them in the database first. Thereafter, it's a matter of how you handle the requests to your API endpoints

Comment: How can I save the 7 pages as text documents and place them in the database?